# Prestashop product width

Tags: php, prestashop

Im trying to put new attributes directly from module (PS 1.6). My objective is new attribute for my guests, that affect price. Its width of element for order. Price calculated based on price for one meter, and width.
And now i have few questions.

1. Where to put that information (width), after my customer will fill it. It will be better if i put it on new table, or better to modify all tables responsible for order? If new table is better, then when i need to pull this data? Only product and order controller? Maybe somebody can help with finding methods/places for that?
2. Product::getPriceStatic is the only method i need to modify for calculating price? I think its easiest way to multiply quantity before return the price, correct?

Maybe somebody have some tips.
Thank You for help in advance.

Comment: I made a module like this and chose to put the width and height information as a customization but you can modify the attributes instead by overriding the Cart::getProducts method. As for the price, override Product::getPriceStatic, it's fine

Comment: Thank You, i was thinking about customization too, maybe its a lot easier to do. But i need to remove "save" button on customization, and move it above "add to basket" button. Its strange when user need to save customization, and then add to  basket